# проблема с вертикальным SeekBar

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Здравствуйте.

Использую кастомный ползунок, но не выходит использовать некоторые методы с `OnSeekBarChangeListener`: `onStartTrackingTouch` и `onStopTrackingTouch` не работают, но работает `onProgressChanged`.

Код `VerticalSeekBar`:

```
public class VerticalSeekBar extends SeekBar {

public VerticalSeekBar(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);
}

@Override
protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    c.rotate(-90);
    c.translate(-getHeight(), 0);
    super.onDraw(c);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!isEnabled()) {
        return false;
    }
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            setProgress(getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight()));
            onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
    }
    return true;
   }
}
```

Слушатели в `onCreate()`:

```
moveSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int progress;
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue, boolean fromUser) {
            conectionTread.write(String.valueOf(progressValue));//Send progress to module
            progress = progressValue;
            Log.d(Tag, "onProgressChanged is work");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            Log.d(Tag, "onStartTrackingTouch is work");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            seekBar.setProgress(20);
            Log.d(Tag, "onStopTrackingTouch is work");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Самое интересное – в конце этого ответа

Методы `onStartTrackingTouch(...)` и `onStopTrackingTouch(...)` не вызываются, как ни странно, потому что в своем `VerticalSeekBar` Вы их не вызываете.

Почему тогда вызывается `onProgressChanged(...)`? – скорее всего потому, что он вызывается где-то непосредственно в суперклассе.

**Как исправить:**

Добавляете в Ваш `VerticalSeekBar` поле:

```
private OnSeekBarChangeListener onChangeListener;
```

переопределяете метод `setOnSeekBarChangeListener(...)`:

```
@Override
public void setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnSeekBarChangeListener onChangeListener){
    this.onChangeListener = onChangeListener;
}
```

и изменяете метод `onTouchEvent(...)`:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!isEnabled()) {
        return false;
    }
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            onChangeListener.onStartTrackingTouch(this);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            int progress = getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight());
            setProgress(progress);
            onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
            onChangeListener.onProgressChanged(this, progress, true);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            onChangeListener.onStopTrackingTouch(this);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Как можно видеть из кода, при соответствующих событиях мы вызываем соответствующие методы, например, если:

```
event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
```

то мы вызываем:

```
onChangeListener.onStartTrackingTouch(this)
```

С остальными методами по аналогии.

### А теперь самое главное!

Насколько я понимаю, Вы хотите реализовать вертикальный `SeekBar`.

Когда-то давно (для `API level < 11`) реализация своего вертикального `SeekBar` была оправдана, но в `API level 11` `SeekBar`'у был добавлен атрибут `android:rotation`, с помощью которого можно повернуть `SeekBar` на определенный угол.

Для того чтобы `SeekBar` был вертикальным, достаточно добавить ему атрибут:

```
android:rotation="270"
```

или

```
android:rotation="90"
```

Comment: за android:rotation="270" знаю, пробовал но в макете начинаются проблемы.Поэтому решил поискать альтернативы.Уже не первый раз помогаете, огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: @UjinUkr, Предварительный просмотр разметки не всегда работает корректно. Лучше проверять непосредственно при выполнении программы.

Comment: странно выходит при этом атрибуте (android:rotation="270"), сам SeekBar расположен вертикально, а вот само поле в котором он должен быть расположен все равно горизонтально, вот это и создавало проблемы